# How to check comma separated values stored in data base column having the given value using linq in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a table named product and category in my sql server database. Product table contains the column category_id to store mapping categories. One product may mapped to any number of categories ex.`category_id(1,25,44,11,21)`, mapping ids will be stored as comma separated string.

Now I want to retrieve the products from product table where the product contains the selected category from dropdown menu using linq.

For example i want to retrieve the products `where category id =1`. My linq  query is

```
var prodlst = (from p in db.Products
           where (p.PCategory_Id.EndsWith(""+categoryid+"")||
           p.PCategory_Id.Contains("," + categoryid + ",") ||
           p.PCategory_Id.Contains("" + categoryid + ",") ||
           p.PCategory_Id.Contains("," + categoryid + ""))
           select new ProductBO
           {
             Id = p.Id,
             Product_Name = p.Name,
             Price = p.Price
    }).ToList();
```

It retrieves all the values where category id = 1 or 11 or 21, but i want to retrieve only if the category id is exactly 1

Comment: thats very risky code, using `contains` syntax in linq is means `like`, thats why your result will show any category contains 1. consider splitting category id first then using `equal` operator to get the exact category you want.

Comment: Do you have control over database design? I think a better design would be to have 3 tables: Products, Categories, ProductCategories (Mapping table) as opposed to storing comma separated CategoryIds.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if EntityFramework can translate this. If it doesn't try make it enumerable.

```
db.Products.Where(t=> PCategory_Id.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Contains(categoryid));

db.Products.AsEnumerable().Where(t=> PCategory_Id.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Contains(categoryid));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in the way of your syntax. Only the 2nd clause needs to be 'Contains' (also I changed Equals to ==) :

```
var prodlst = (from p in db.Products
       where ( (p.PCategory_Id == categoryid) ||
       p.PCategory_Id.Contains("," + categoryid + ",") ||
       p.PCategory_Id.StartsWith(categoryid + ",") ||
       p.PCategory_Id.EndsWith("," + categoryid))
       select new ProductBO
       {
         Id = p.Id,
         Product_Name = p.Name,
         Price = p.Price
}).ToList();
```

Comment: above code throwing this run time error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."  'Use == instead of Equals'  'where p.PCategory_Id == ""+categoryid '

Answer (score 0):

```
var prodlst = (from p in db.Products
                               where (p.PCategory_Id == ""+categoryid ||
                               p.PCategory_Id.Contains("," + categoryid + ",") ||
                               p.PCategory_Id.StartsWith(categoryid + ",") ||
                               p.PCategory_Id.EndsWith("," + categoryid))
                               select new ProductBO
                               {
                                   Id = p.Id,
                                   Product_Name = p.Name,
                                   Price = p.Price
                               }).ToList();
```